# In an NGINX / uWSGI / Django stack, will Django be notified if a response times out before the client has received it?

Tags: python, django, http, nginx, uwsgi

I have an API written in Django. The application server is uWSGI and the web server is NGINX.

Therefore, a typical request follows this path:

```
Client --> NGINX --> uWSGI --> Django
```

A typical response follows this path:

```
Django --> uWSGI --> NGINX --> Client
```

My question is related to the last link in this chain (when NGINX is sending the response to the client).

If this times out, or the connection is broken before NGINX can finish the transfer, will Django be notified of the failure?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking here, by that time django has already sent a response so I'm not sure why it would need to be notified

Comment: @Sayse If the client does not receive the response I would like to roll the transaction back.

Comment: I'm not sure thats possible since you'd need to send another response back on something that has been deemed broken. Although that whole step should for the most part take milliseconds so the window is very small

Comment: @Sayse Sadly, some of these connections are extremely congested. Hopefully someone knows for sure.

Comment: I'll chip in and say that once a request leaves django it's out of the equation. You could have something in your API (like travel apps do) that makes clients _confirm_ the request before it's final.

Comment: Agree with the above, its the same reason amazon make you confirm your purchase before its finalized (they also send an email confirmation)